# Remove All Query Arg

Tags: urls

Is there a way to remove all query arg parameter in the URL added via `add_query_arg();` without knowing the query key available for removal?

I'm looking for this kind of function `remove_query_arg_all();` currently I'm removing the query_arg via preg_match REQUEST_URI, but not sure if it will cause any problem in the future.

Comment: Did you try searching stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explode URL by `?` and take the first part:

```
$url = explode( '?', esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( array() ) ) );

$no_query_args = $url[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line if your aim is to remove all of the params from the current `$_GET`

```
remove_query_arg(array_keys($_GET))
```